# Why in InsertHead function is l.head=p but not p=l.head if p=l.head, will there be any change? please answer for me thanks

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I get an error and
my code is below:
Why in InsertHead function is l.head=p but not p=l.head if p=l.head, will there be any change? please answer for me thanks

```
void InsertHead(list &l, int x)
{node *p ;`
p = GetNode(x) ;
if (p==NULL)
{
cout<<" node cannot be created!";
exit(1);
}
if (l.head==NULL) 
l.head = l.tail = p ;
else
{
p->next = l.head ;
l.head = p ;
}
```

Comment: where did you get the code from? What is `list`, `node` and `GetNode` ?

Comment: `p` seems to be the new node to be inserted in the list. Modifying the local variable `p` will not have an effect on the list `l`. The question is unclear

Comment: if i post all my code it will be too long so i'll just post the code i asked and i'm so sorry if you don't like this

Comment: it does not matter whether I like it or not. Posting a [mcve] is required for questions about code

Comment: I will learn from my experience next time and sincerely apologize for this

Answer (score 0):

suppose this is original list  **l->head = somenode**
when  invoke **InsertHead**
first you should make a new node, invoke **GetNode**,then you get a new node **p**,
then you should add this node to list
**p->next = l->head (somenode)**
now the whole list become **p->somenode->.....**,new head of whole list is **p**,but  **l->head** not change.so you should call **l->head = p**

Answer (score -1):

**Difference between l.head=p and p=l.head**

`l.head = p` means you are assigning `p`'s address to `l.head` and

`p=l.head` means you are assigning `l.head`'s address to `p`

Example

Suppose you have two var

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
```

now if you do `a = b`, `a` becomes 10 and `b` remains the same i.e 10

and if you do `b = a`, `b` becomes 5 and `a` remains the same i.e 5

Comment: `l.head = p` assigns `p`s value to `l.head`. `p`s adress would be `&p`

Comment: So if i assign l.head=p then my p becomes the head of the list and if before p->next =l.head so if p=l.head then p=p->next is absurd right?